# Were there ever any plans to have Han Solo show up in the prequels?

Tags: star-wars, han-solo, prequels

Han Solo is arguably the only Original Trilogy main character not to appear in the Prequel Trilogy.

Does anyone know if there was ever any plan for Han Solo to appear in the prequels?

Comment: No.  They wanted to keep everything cool out of the prequels.

Comment: Except R2-D2 and Chewbacca.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

**Actually, yes. There were initial plans for Han Solo to show up in *Revenge of the Sith*.**

[Screencrush has an article about it.](http://screencrush.com/star-wars-concept-art-han-solo/)

The book *The Art of Star Wars Episode 3: Revenge of the Sith* includes concept art of a young Han Solo and two blurbs about the original idea.

Concept Artist Ian McCaig explains:

> It’s not in the script anymore, but we were told that Han Solo was on Kashyyyk [in 'Revenge of the Sith'] and that he was being raised by Chewbacca. He’s such a persnickety guy later on – he always has to have the best of everything – so I thought it’d be great if when he was a kid, he was an absolute slob.

and it provides a dated script note

> January 10-24, 2003
>
> Lucas asks for a conference room on Kashyyyk - and a costume for a young Han Solo, who is slated to meet Yoda on this planet and actually help him to locate general Grievous. His one and only costume and character style are approved as soon as they're presented.

[image: solo concept art]

[image: solo family portrait]

Solo was originally scripted with one line of dialogue. The draft with this line is included in *The Making Of Star Wars Revenge of the Sith*.

> HAN SOLO
>
> I found part of a transmitter droid near the east bay… I think it’s still sending and receiving signals.
>
> YODA
>
> Good. Good. Track this we can back to the source. Find General Grievous, we might…

[image: script scan]

It's worth noting that this concept was not exactly a new one. The Annotated Screenplays (published in 1997) mention this idea even back then.

> George Lucas: "The idea was that Han solo was an orphan. He was raised by Wookiees, befriended Chewbacca, and they went off."

Comment: Wow.  That man's total disregard for continuity never ceases to amaze me.  "Han knowing Yoda as a boy, even though he clearly didn't know the name when Luke said it on Hoth?  I LOVE IT!  Chewbacca being Han's father, even though Han treats him like an asshole constantly in the original trilogy?  MAKE IT HAPPEN!"

Comment: @WadCheber : This is the same man who wanted to name the main character "Lucas Starkiller" after himself, and would only compromise as far as "Luke" in the final version.

Comment: False. According to the annotated screenplays for the OT, the story synopsis dated May 1, 1975 was titled "The Adventures of Luke Starkiller Episode 1: The Star Wars". Additionally, "in the rough and first drafts we meet General Luke Skywalker on Aquilae as he walks into the middle of a meeting that King Kayos is having with the High Senate."

Comment: @phantom42 Re: *Lucas Starkiller*: It was kind of a joke.  By the way, I +1'ed your answer because it is awesome.

Comment: Did some more digging. I believe the scan of the draft script may be from *The Making of Episode 3*, which I think I may have a copy of at home to check tonight.

Comment: Good lord this would have been upsetting.

Comment: @WadCheber You can't really blame him for something he left out.

Comment: Thank God they left this out. The prequels screwed up existing continuity enough as it is.

Comment: I wish I could unlearn this.  Great answer ... ***horrible*** concept.