# Who were Han Solo's parents?

Tags: star-wars

*The Force Awakens* brought us more footage of our favorite smuggler, but did nothing to explain who Han's parents were or in what circumstances he was raised. Throughout the movies, it's remained unclear whether Han even knows own his ancestry.

Because my exposure to the novels has been extremely limited, it's entirely possible that Han Solo's upbringing has already been explained and I simply didn't know about it.

I'm looking for canon (or even EU content) to fill in some of his family history. We know that Han [served in the Empire](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/102084/han-solos-military-life) before he took up smuggling, but much of his story has now been overwritten or left unexplained.

What kind of people were Han Solo's parents? Did they lead normal civilian lives?

Comment: Worth noting: Lucas envisioned that [Han was an orphan raised by wookiees](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/100621/5184), but these details were never put on screen.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### Disney canon:

No information. At all. It's as if he was created by Midichlorians.

### EU/Legends:

His parents were [Jaina](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Jaina_%28Elder%29) (nothing is known about her except that Han mentioned his ship Jaina's Light was named after her in "Routine — Star Wars Tales 2) and [Jonash Suul](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Jonash_Solo) *(source: The Courtship of Princess Leia, EU/Legends canon, <strike>to everyone's deep regret</strike>).*

This came out when C-3PO was researching Solo's family background, to prove that he was a worthy suitor to Princess Leia (compared to Hapan Prince Isolder).

> “But Korol Solo married and fathered his first son on Duro nearly sixty years ago, and because of the wars and turmoil, that son never returned home. His name was Dalla Solo, but he changed his name to Dalla Suul to hide his identity during the Clone Wars. **His firstborn son was Jonash Suul, and the first son of Jonash Suul was named Han Suul - who changed his name back to Han Solo**. Obviously, Han knew of his royal lineage, but for reasons that are quite beyond me, he’s also tampered with records back on Corellia in an effort to hide that lineage!” *(CoPL, Chapter 6)*

Nothing was really known about them even in EU/Legends canon aside from the names and the paragraph above. They both died before Han turned 7.

Answer (score 8):

In the Star Wars expanded universe, their names were **Jonash and Jaina Solo**.

They are listed in the second family tree [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solo_family#Family_trees). From [Wookieepedia](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/House_of_Solo) (sourced to [The Paradise Snare](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/The_Paradise_Snare)):

> Han Solo, an alleged member of the House who was born in poverty to Jonash Solo in 29 BBY, became a celebrated hero of the Rebel Alliance.

Han's father Jonash Solo has [his own Wookieepedia page](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Jonash_Solo), and is mentioned in [The Courtship of Princess Leia](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/The_Courtship_of_Princess_Leia). Han's mother Jaina Solo also has [a short Wookieepedia page](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Jaina_(Elder)), and is mentioned in [Star Wars Tales 2](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Tales_2).

Answer (score 3):

In Disney canon, according to [*Han Solo & Chewbacca 1*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Han_Solo_%26_Chewbacca_1), his father was named [Ovan](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Ovan), and worked in the Corellian Engineering Corporation shipyards. It's been established that he abandoned Han, and eventually died in 24 BBY.

Han seemingly briefly reunites with Ovan in *Han Solo & Chewbacca 2*, although it's less than amicable, and Han has his doubts if they are the real deal.

[image: Han deals with "Ovan"]

> And indeed, it turns out to be [Corbus Tyrus](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Corbus_Tyra).