# Are there any consequences to Chewbacca's life debt to Han Solo after The Force Awakens?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens

With some reference to (some spoilers included): [Chewie's life-debt to Han?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/111535/chewies-life-debt-to-han)

What does a Wookiee life debt entail? How similar is it to the definition turned up by Google:

> A life debt is a literary phenomenon in which someone whose life is saved or spared by another becomes indebted or in some way connected to their savior. A life debt can only be paid off by saving the original savior’s life in return.

For those who have watched the movie, what implications are there to Chewbacca’s life debt for what happened to Han Solo? Is it possible he may have lost his honour or failed his ancestors or anything to that degree?

Edit: This isn’t a question of whether the life debt ended. It’s about the repercussions, given what has happened in the movie, due to Chewbacca’s preexisting life debt. Mostly from a Wookiee’s point of view.

Comment: Ignoring the fact that Disney canon says nothing about Chewbacca having a life debt?

Comment: @WadCheber I'm not really focusing on whether it has been lifted like that other question. I'm asking if there are any consequences to the nature of how it apparently ended because of what happened in the movie. Did Chewbacca "fail"?

Comment: As far as I can remember, we simply don't have ANY canon information to know. Even in EU, there was never ANY ANY discussion of what the life debt rules are as far as when one family member attacks another (considering that Chewie considered his life debt extending to Leia and 3 kids)