# Does a Wookiee Life Debt Ever End?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, chewbacca

The rules of Wookiee life debts seem very harsh in Legends. Chewbacca remained with Han for decades after pledging himself. The life-debt extended to Han's wife, children, and brother-in-law as well. In this period, he saved their lives any number of times, such as helping save Han from Jabba. Even Chewie's death didn't end things, as his son and nephew took over the debt.

If the debt is ever-growing, and neither saving the debtor's life nor dying releases the debtee, does anything end the debt?

---

This question specifically pertains to Legends, as according to this [answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/134458/51226), life debts aren't quite as drastic in canon.

Comment: Answer:  It's a plot device.

Comment: Notably other cultures also have their own version of life debts (the Gungans, for example) that are confirmed to be able to be fulfilled, *at the decision of the individual who is indebted.*

Answer (score 1):

**Yes, they do, but only when the wookiee dies.**

According to the canon novel [*Alphabet Squadron*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Alphabet_Squadron_(novel)), a life debt is (theoretically) permanent

> “What’s a life debt?” Chass asked.
>
> “It’s a promise,” Wyl said. “An oath to serve the person who saved you from death. An oath to stand by her side forever, knowing your lives can’t be disentangled.”

---

Wookieepedia ([Legends](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki)) states that a life debt occurs...

> if a person's life was saved by another, the saved person was obligated to pledge their life to protect and look after their savior

And to pledge one's life means that they would protect their savior until that life ends.

And it even says that they will sacrifice their life if necessary

> ... even to the point of sacrificing their own life, if necessary.

It even shows that this pertains to Wookiee life debts in the example of the alleged first Wookiee life debt.

> Urothko was nearly killed in the Shadowlands, only to be rescued by an elder called Stalpaac. After being saved, Urothko pledged his life to Staalpac.

Comment: This is a better source. However, the first part is irrelevant to my question since I stated I was specifically looking at Legends. For the second part, do you know what Wookieepedia is sourcing and if it applies specifically to Wookiee life debts?

Comment: found it, it references A Guide to the Star Wars Universe.

Comment: @RogueJedi As to if it specifically pertains to Wookie life debts, yes. It in fact referenced the first Wookiee Life debt made by Urothko to another Wookiee by pledging his life to him and thereby starting the tradition.

Comment: @RogueJedi Every _person_ of a culture will treat each _tradition_ differently. Chewies family was just off the charts with their adherence, at least the 2 generations we see. Others might never even admit to having been in a life-debt situation. Like Klingon Honor - individual adherence varries.